# How can i manage images dynamically using pdfkit in nodejs

Tags: node.js, pdfkit

Q : i wanted to manage images dynamically using pdfkit in nodejs. and also i want to addPage if images not fitted in current page.

Code :

```
const doc = new PDFDocument({
    size: 'letter'
});



function photographs(doc) {
    arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
    doc
        .fillColor('#1c5695')
        .fontSize(10)
        .font('Helvetica-Bold')
        .text('PHOTOGRAPHS', 10, doc.y, {
            width: 300,
            align: 'left'
        })
    arr.forEach((element, i) => {
        doc.image('images/pdflogo.png', {
            align: 'center',
            fit: [100, 100]
        })
    });

}
```

so my question is how to manage x and y position of image , so it'll manage space dynamically.
e.g first 6 img set into 1st row then rest will set on 2nd row and so on..